# Extracting multiple substrings from a string, based on the same rule

Tags: bash

I am trying to get file extensions from an input string, in order to determine what kind of files they are.

I have found many solutions online, and I have found one in particular that works almost perfectly. Using grep with perl regular expressions, I am able to filter out all the unwanted bits and I get a string, composed of file extensions separated by spaces.

```
grep -oP '(?<=\.).*?(?=")'
```

is what I have right now, which produces an output of

```
jpg jpg jpg jpg jpg jpg flac flac flac ...flac flac flac flac flac flac flac ...flac flac flac flac flac cue log m3u
```

when fed the following set of files (excuse the long string, but that's what is fed to grep, the gist of it is that some filenames contain an ellipsis at the end, which throws off my grep logic):

```
"Гарик Сукачёв и Неприкасаемые - Grand Collection (2002)/images/booklet2-3.jpg" "Гарик Сукачёв и Неприкасаемые - Grand Collection (2002)/images/booklet4.jpg" "Гарик Сукачёв и Неприкасаемые - Grand Collection (2002)/images/cd.jpg" "Гарик Сукачёв и Неприкасаемые - Grand Collection (2002)/images/cover.jpg" "Гарик Сукачёв и Неприкасаемые - Grand Collection (2002)/images/inlay.jpg" "Гарик Сукачёв и Неприкасаемые - Grand Collection (2002)/images/matrix.jpg" "Гарик Сукачёв и Неприкасаемые - Grand Collection (2002)/01 Моя бабушка курит трубку.flac" "Гарик Сукачёв и Неприкасаемые - Grand Collection (2002)/02 Свободу Анджеле Дэвис!.flac" "Гарик Сукачёв и Неприкасаемые - Grand Collection (2002)/03 За окошком месяц май.flac" "Гарик Сукачёв и Неприкасаемые - Grand Collection (2002)/04 Знаю я, есть края....flac" "Гарик Сукачёв и Неприкасаемые - Grand Collection (2002)/05 Ольга.flac" "Гарик Сукачёв и Неприкасаемые - Grand Collection (2002)/06 Я милого узнаю по походке.flac" "Гарик Сукачёв и Неприкасаемые - Grand Collection (2002)/07 Белый колпак.flac" "Гарик Сукачёв и Неприкасаемые - Grand Collection (2002)/08 Прощай, мой друг.flac" "Гарик Сукачёв и Неприкасаемые - Grand Collection (2002)/09 Дорожная.flac" "Гарик Сукачёв и Неприкасаемые - Grand Collection (2002)/10 10 000 километров.flac" "Гарик Сукачёв и Неприкасаемые - Grand Collection (2002)/11 Брёл, брёл, брёл....flac" "Гарик Сукачёв и Неприкасаемые - Grand Collection (2002)/12 Напои меня водой.flac" "Гарик Сукачёв и Неприкасаемые - Grand Collection (2002)/13 Города, где дымится асфальт.flac" "Гарик Сукачёв и Неприкасаемые - Grand Collection (2002)/14 Песня вольного стрелка (Белла Чао!).flac" "Гарик Сукачёв и Неприкасаемые - Grand Collection (2002)/15 Нулевой километр.flac" "Гарик Сукачёв и Неприкасаемые - Grand Collection (2002)/Grand Сollection.cue" "Гарик Сукачёв и Неприкасаемые - Grand Collection (2002)/Гарик Сукачёв и ''Неприкасаемые'' - Grand Сollection.log" "Гарик Сукачёв и Неприкасаемые - Grand Collection (2002)/Гарик Сукачёв и ''Неприкасаемые'' - Grand Сollection.m3u"
```

While I do get all the needed extensions, I also get a bunch of unneeded dots if the filename happens to contain them. I recognize that I have to use the repetition feature of grep, namely {1}, but I can not for the life of me figure out where I have to put it to make it work. The resulting regex should only give me the file extension of each file, and nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sed` will do that for you.

```
sed -E ' s/"[^"]+[.]+([^"]+)"/\1/g' data
jpg jpg jpg jpg jpg jpg flac flac flac flac flac flac flac flac flac flac flac flac flac flac flac cue log m3u
```

`"`       a quote
`[^"]+`   followed by one or more non-quotes
`[.]+`    followed by one or more dots
`([^"]+)` followed by one or more non-quotes *that we remember*
`"`       followed by a quote,

`\1` replaced by just the part we remembered from each sequence,
`g`  repeated across the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex if you want to keep using grep and PCRE `(?!\.)[\w]+(?=")` It uses a negative lookahead, that means it matches a pattern only if not followed by another pattern. In this case, it matches the pattern `[\w]` only if not followed by a dot. You can test it [here](https://regexr.com/4df71) and also find a more detailed explanation.